# HTML/CSS Why does the button keep disappearing when scaling width?

Tags: html, css, button, responsive

I tried to make a responsive website for a project on school but this button keeps disappearing when I scale the width of the website.

**Good View:**

[image]

**button disappears at tablet and mobile view:**

[image]

**How can I fix this?**

**The Code:**

```css
html * {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: ITC Franklin;
  src: url("ITC_Franklin_Book.otf");
}
h1, p, h3 {
  font-family: ITC Franklin;
}
#results img{
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 6%;
}
#wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
header{
  z-index: 1;
}
header h1{
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-left: 25.5%;
}
.knopje {
  width: 50%; 
  height: 10%; 
  border: medium solid grey; 
  margin-left: 25%;
}

/* MENU */
#nav li {
  background-color: white;
  height: 50%;
  line-height: 40px;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin-left: 26%;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

/* body */
body {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  max-width:100%; 
  background-image:url("image/background.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
}

/* Header */
header {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2.5% 4.5% 3.5% 10%;
  width: 82.5%;
}
header img {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: -3%;
  margin-top: -2%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 9%;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Actions screen LINKS */
div #linkerdiv{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 7.5%;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  margin-bottom: 3.5%;
  width: 40%;
}
input #poll{
  margin-left: 5%;
}
#linkerdiv img{
  width:45%;
  height:40%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#linkerdiv p{
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
#linkerdiv li{
  font-family: ITC Franklin;
  margin-left: 5%;
  list-style: none;
}
h3 {
  margin-left: 5%;
}
textarea{
  border-radius: 30px;
  max-width: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

/* Presentatoren div rechts */
div #rechterdiv{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-family: ITC Franklin;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 500px;
  margin-right: 7.5%;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  margin-bottom: 3.5%;
  width: 40%;
}
#rechterdiv h2 {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 13pt;
}
#rechterdiv p{
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

/*BREAKPOINT1*/

/*BREAKPOINT 2*/
@media screen and (max-width:40em) {
  html, body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  header h1{
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  div #linkerdiv {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 7.5%;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    margin-bottom: 3.5%;
    width: 87%;
  }    
  div #rechterdiv {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    float: right;
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 3.5%;
    margin-right: 5.5%;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    width: 87%;
  }
  #w3-display-container mySlides {
    z-index: 5;
  }
  #w3-btn-floating w3-hover-dark-grey w3-display-right {
    z-index: 10;
  }
  #w3-btn-floating w3-hover-dark-grey w3-display-left {
    z-index: 10;
  }
  header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 2.5% 4.5% 3.5% 10%;
    width: 82.5%;
  }
  header img {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: -7%;
    margin-top: -2%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>3 Op Reis Second Screen</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Second screen" />
    <meta name="author" content="Berkay Bayir" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="3opreis second screen" />
    <link href="style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper" data-role="page" class="ui-content">
      <header>
        <img src="image/logotje.png" alt="logo"/>
        <nav id="header" role="header text">
          <ul>
            <h1>3 Op Reis Second Screen App</h1>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <div id="linkerdiv">
        <img src="image/3.png" alt="logo"/>
        <img src="image/4.png" alt="logo"/>
        <p>
          In de aflevering van 15 januari 2017, die zometeen zal beginnen, bezoeken de presentatoren de landen Egypte, Italië en Canada. Ze gaan langs de steden Cairo, San Marino en Toronto.

          Hieronder kun je stemmen wat voor jou het interessant lijkt.
          De resultaten zullen aan het begin van de aflevering op tv getoond worden.

        </p>
        <ul>
          <form id="formulier">
            <h3>Poll: Naar welk land zou jij het liefst heen willen gaan?</h3>
            <li><input type="radio" id="poll" name="stemmen" value="1"> Egypte</li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="poll" name="stemmen" value="2"> Italië</li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="poll" name="stemmen" value="3"> Canada</li>
            <input type="button" class="knopje" value="Stem!" onclick="thankYou()">
          </form>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="rechterdiv">
        <div class="w3-container">
          <h2>Zondag 15 januari 2017 om 19.50 uur</h2>
          <p>Bekijk wie welk land bezoekt!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
          <a class="w3-btn-floating w3-hover-dark-grey w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</a>
          <a class="w3-btn-floating w3-hover-dark-grey w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</a>
          <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
            <img src="image/1.png" style="width:100%">
            <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
              Geraldine in San Marino, Italië
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
            <img src="image/2.png" style="width:100%">
            <div class="w3-display-bottomright w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
              Dennis in Cairo, Egypte
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: It's just a percentage related problem that you defined in css file. Rather I suggest you to use bootstrap.

Comment: I had to make it myself, can't use bootstrap for this project.. :(

Comment: Anyway, Bootstrap is not a solution to learn, you better understand what you code, this is the reason you have to do it yourself I think

Comment: You're right, i tried changing a lot in the CSS but just couldnt fix this issue

Comment: don't give things a fixed height that is why your content is overflowing in thinner screen resolutions - if you want items to be equal heights on the same row, have a look at using `display:flex`.  Also `h1` cannot be a child of `ul`

Answer (score 1):

What is causing your problem is that your `div #linkerdiv` rule is defining the height to be `500px`, so when the screen is narrow its content becomes higher than that, and everything is overflowed!

Here you have two options:

1. Change the height for all screen widths by setting it to a new value
2. Make a change to your [**media query**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to change the height on narrow screens only.

I updated your code to use a media query as an example:

```css
html * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: ITC Franklin;
  src: url("ITC_Franklin_Book.otf");
}
h1,
p,
h3 {
  font-family: ITC Franklin;
}
#results img {
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 6%;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  z-index: 1;
}
header h1 {
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-left: 25.5%;
}
.knopje {
  width: 50%;
  height: 10%;
  border: medium solid grey;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
/* MENU */

#nav li {
  background-color: white;
  height: 50%;
  line-height: 40px;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin-left: 26%;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  position: relative;
}
/* body */

body {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-image: url("image/background.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
}
/* Header */

header {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2.5% 4.5% 3.5% 10%;
  width: 82.5%;
}
header img {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: -3%;
  margin-top: -2%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 9%;
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Actions screen LINKS */

div #linkerdiv {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 7.5%;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  margin-bottom: 3.5%;
  width: 40%;
}
input #poll {
  margin-left: 5%;
}
#linkerdiv img {
  width: 45%;
  height: 40%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#linkerdiv p {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
#linkerdiv li {
  font-family: ITC Franklin;
  margin-left: 5%;
  list-style: none;
}
h3 {
  margin-left: 5%;
}
textarea {
  border-radius: 30px;
  max-width: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}
/* Presentatoren div rechts */

div #rechterdiv {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-family: ITC Franklin;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 500px;
  margin-right: 7.5%;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  margin-bottom: 3.5%;
  width: 40%;
}
#rechterdiv h2 {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 13pt;
}
#rechterdiv p {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
/*BREAKPOINT1*/

/*BREAKPOINT 2*/

@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
  html,
  body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  div #linkerdiv {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 700px;
    margin-left: 7.5%;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    margin-bottom: 3.5%;
    width: 87%;
  }
  div #rechterdiv {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    float: right;
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 3.5%;
    margin-right: 5.5%;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    width: 87%;
  }
  #w3-display-container mySlides {
    z-index: 5;
  }
  #w3-btn-floating w3-hover-dark-grey w3-display-right {
    z-index: 10;
  }
  #w3-btn-floating w3-hover-dark-grey w3-display-left {
    z-index: 10;
  }
  header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 2.5% 4.5% 3.5% 10%;
    width: 82.5%;
  }
  header img {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: -7%;
    margin-top: -2%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>3 Op Reis Second Screen</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Second screen" />
  <meta name="author" content="Berkay Bayir" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="3opreis second screen" />
  <link href="style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript" async defer></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper" data-role="page" class="ui-content">

    <header>
      <img src="image/logotje.png" alt="logo" />
      <nav id="header" role="header text">

        <ul>

          <h1>3 Op Reis Second Screen App</h1>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="linkerdiv">
      <img src="image/3.png" alt="logo" />
      <img src="image/4.png" alt="logo" />

      <p>
        In de aflevering van 15 januari 2017, die zometeen zal beginnen, bezoeken de presentatoren de landen Egypte, Italië en Canada. Ze gaan langs de steden Cairo, San Marino en Toronto. Hieronder kun je stemmen wat voor jou het interessant lijkt. De resultaten
        zullen aan het begin van de aflevering op tv getoond worden.

      </p>
      <ul>
        <form id="formulier">
          <h3>Poll: Naar welk land zou jij het liefst heen willen gaan?</h3>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" id="poll" name="stemmen" value="1">Egypte</li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" id="poll" name="stemmen" value="2">Italië</li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" id="poll" name="stemmen" value="3">Canada</li>
          <input type="button" class="knopje" value="Stem!" onclick="thankYou()">
        </form>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="rechterdiv">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <h2>Zondag 15 januari 2017 om 19.50 uur</h2>
        <p>Bekijk wie welk land bezoekt!</p>
      </div>

      <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">

        <a class="w3-btn-floating w3-hover-dark-grey w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="w3-btn-floating w3-hover-dark-grey w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</a>

        <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
          <img src="image/1.png" style="width:100%">
          <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
            Geraldine in San Marino, Italië
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
          <img src="image/2.png" style="width:100%">
          <div class="w3-display-bottomright w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
            Dennis in Cairo, Egypte
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked, it's only the tablet view that breaks now. Guess i'll have to fix that then it's done :)

Comment: Yes , you can use another `media query` for tablets, If you see that useful kindly mark it as the correct answer for future references :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `linkerdiv` element has a fixed height. When the **window** is resized, the elements take more place on the vertical axis as the `width` of your element is decreasing.
You should set an **automatic height** to keep the *children elements* inside the *container* :

```
#linkerdiv {
    height: auto;
}
```

And I think you shouldn't put your form elements in a list, a better behaviour would be to correctly style it :

```
<form id="formulier">
    <h3>Poll: Naar welk land zou jij het liefst heen willen gaan?</h3>
    <input type="radio" id="poll" name="stemmen" value="1">Egypte<br>
    <input type="radio" id="poll" name="stemmen" value="2">Italië<br>
    <input type="radio" id="poll" name="stemmen" value="3">Canada<br>
    <input type="button" class="knopje" value="Stem!" onclick="thankYou()">
</form>
```

in your CSS :

```
#formulier {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Then continue to style it as you need.
[MDN - flex box properties (to help you understand the CSS I wrote)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)